# Images will not show

Tags: javascript, html, css

My images or the iframe video i added to my site do not show. I'm not entirely sure as i do not have much experience with javascript, but i feel it may be the root of the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
   
function hidedivs() {
 $("#content").children().hide();
};




$(document).ready(function() {
 hidedivs();
 $("#submenu").hide();
  $("works").click(function(){
            $("#submenu").toggle('Slide');
            return false;
  });
    
     $("nav a").click(function(event){
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  hidedivs();
  $(url).toggle();   
  $(url).children().hide();  
  $(url).find("h1, p, li, img").toggle();  
  event.preventDefault();
 });
    
  $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".theunwakingworld").click(function() {
         $(".theunwakingworld").toggle();
         
         });  
       });   
  
});
```

```css
ul
{
 list-style-type:none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

li
{
 display:inline;
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: grey;
 font-size: 120%;
 padding: 5px;
 margin:0;
}

a:hover, a:visited{
 color: black;
}

#wrapper {
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:19px 0px 0px 301px;
    padding:106px 0px 0px 0px;
}


#submenu {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    font-size:60%;
    font-family:Courier New, Courier, monospace;
}


#theunkwakingworld {
overflow:hidden;
display:inline-block;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

 <div id="wrapper">
 <nav>
     <ul id="menu">
         <li> <a href=".works">Works</a></li>
   <li> <a href=".about">About</a></li>
            <li> <a href=".contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
  <ul id="submenu" class="works">
    
    <li> <a href=".blurg">Blurg</a></li>
    /
                <li> <a href=".theunwakingworld">The Unwaking World</a></li>
            

  </ul>
    </nav>
        <section id="content">
    <div class="theunwakingworld">
    <h1>The Unwaking World</h1>
    <img src="images/photography/manfloor.jpg" width="1000" height="500">
    <img src="images/photography/trainstation.jpg" width="1000" height="500">
    <img src="images/photography/oldfriends.jpg" width="1000" height="500">
    
    
  </div>
                    
                    <div class="blurg">
    <h1>Blurg</h1>
    <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/56594925" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> <p><a href="http://vimeo.com/56594925"></a>
</a> 

    
  </div>
   </section>
 </div>

       

</body>
```

Comment: You have a $(document).ready functions defined inside another $(document).ready function.  I doubt one inside will ever fire.

Comment: I removed the second $(document) ready which toggles the div 'theunwakingworld' and added those two lines of code into the first $(document).ready, but im still running into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it simply looks like the path to your images and video player are not available to the script.  I can see the outlines of the places where the images are supposed to be but it will never work here with local paths like that.  The image directory needs to reside inside the same directory as your index page that contains all the html,css and javascript.  Your directory layout should look something like this:

```
htdocs/
    index.html
    images/
        photography/
            manfloor.jpg
            trainstation.jpg
            oldfriends.jpg
```

And try adding a protocol to your player src:

```
http://player.vimeo.com/video/56594925
```

OK, I think I have it.  Your iframe was not being shown but the rest of the links and text were.  Try simply adding "iframe" to the line below:

```
$(url).find("h1, p, li, img, iframe").toggle();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, i'll give it a go asap and get back to you

Comment: Great thanks, i managed to get the video to appear so thats all good! Its really strange though with the images, because they don't seem to be appearing even in my localhost which is really strange because the images are all available in the folders.

Comment: @ user2043607, See my edited answer above and make sure your directory structure looks like that.  I can't think of a reason why your images wouldn't show.  I got your code to work on my local machine using the above directory structure.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I managed to get the images to show now. It may have been an issue with my htaccess file, and also some rookie html mistakes. thanks so much for your help.